# Save the user_id of a logged in user when submitting a form in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zfcuser

I want to save the users `user_id` along the data he submits via a form. This is in my controller:

**The controller**:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $testing = new Testing();
            $form->setInputFilter($testing->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity();  // user logged in?
                $user = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity(); //get identity
                $user_id = $user->getID(); //gets the user-id, output: number, eg. 18



                $testing->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getTestingTable()->saveTesting($testing);

                // Redirect to iaps test
                return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/testing/iaps4');
            }
        }

        return array('form' => $form);


    }
```

If I `print_r($user_id)` the output will be plain and simple `18`. 
I tried several things that did not work, here the most promising ones:

- a seperate `exchangeArray` for the user_id only. Unfortunately, it
  only generates an empty entry in my database along the data form.
- combine the `$testing->exchangeArray($form->getData());` with the
  user_id data, obviously no success here either.

The thing is, I kinda know what I need: the plain output `18` from the `$user->getID();` won't help me, because I need to asign this number to the `user_id` column in the database along the data submitted by the user with the id `user_id`.

I'm using Zend Framework 2.3.3, ZF-Commons/ZfcBase 0.0.1 and ZF-Commons/ZfcUser 1.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge user_id with the data from your form in a single array with array_merge :

```
$testing->exchangeArray(array_merge(
    $form->getData(),
    ['user_id' => $user->getID()]
));
```